after migrating from intel to arm mac, how to update brew?
I've used apple migration tool to copy all my user data and applications from an intel macbook to m3 macbook. I've noticed that my entire stack uses rosetta, which makes sense since old binaries were copied. I have brew -> fish shell; brew -> conda -> python. How to upgrade / change tools to use arm versions?

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/410825/apple-silicon-port-all-homebrew-packages-under-usr-local-opt-to-opt-homebrew could help. If you need additional help, please move your question to apple.stackexchange.com - unless this is in any way related to programming. If this is the case, please share more details by editing your question

First, a few CLI tools that will help navigate the journey: arch to check what architecture is used in current shell, outputs i386 for intel binaries and arm64 for apple silicon; file to inspect a binary and see if it is a arm or intel binary.
In general, it makes sense to completely uninstall brew and install it again, in my opinion. You can do so with $ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)". Now, in order to get a arm brew installed, you need to have arch == arm64. If you are running a shell that itself uses i386 arch, it will install i386 brew. I've ran built-in zsh, and installed new brew there, then reinstalled my fish shell. Note that arm64 installation of brew will live in /opt, e.g.
$ which brew                                                                               
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew

You might need to delete folders of tools in /usr/local installed by old brew. I've seen some guides about renaming old brew with an alias and installing side by side, but this was too confusing.
